# Akka Stream source queue : how to limit insertion in a queue with backpressure (from a traversable interface)

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I have a backpressured queue, a flow reading the queue and a process feeding this queue in background. (the consumption of the queue starts before the end of the queue feeding).

The feeding is done from a traversable interface that reads a database. 
The only method I have on this interface is foreach. I'm feeding the queue like this :

```
 def sourceFromTraversable[T](traversable: Traversable[T]) = {
 val (queue, source) = Source.queue[T](queueSize, OverflowStrategy.backpressure).preMaterialize()
    Future {
      traversable.foreach{
        element =>
          Await.result(queue.offer(element), Duration.Inf)
      }
    }.map(_ => queue.complete())
  source
}
```

I'm using Await.result because if I don't, the backpressure is not applied to the traversable, i.e. it will pull the database too much, because it will run a lot of Futures in parallel instead of waiting.

Is there a cleaner way (without Await.result) to achieve this with an interface like traversable?

Thanks

Comment: I think I've missed the high-level problem you are trying to solve; is it to create a `Source` which avoids pulling more than one element at a time from a `Traversable` returned by the database?

Comment: @Alec yep, exactly! I'm trying to do it with Source.fromIterator(() => traversable.toIterator) but it seems it loads all the traversable before consumming (maybe a thread config problem?)

Comment: Gotcha. The `Source.fromIterator` has the stream semantics you want - it just seems that `traversable.toIterator` is being overly eager. Does the traversable not get eagerly loaded early in the `foreach` call? Any chance you could mention where this `Traversable` is coming from?

Comment: @Alec It comes from a company home-made jdbc framework :(

Comment: @Alec I can see the traversable beeing fully loaded  (with traces) when I call .toIterator

Comment: Ooof. Without having some other method on the traversable (other than `foreach`, since that doesn't let you properly control when each element will get visited) I don't see a better way through this. Is there really no other way to iterate through elements? If not, perhaps there is a good DB driver reason for this?

Comment: @Alec yeah I think we will have to refactor this jdbc layer :)
Thanks for you help!